# Groovy compilation error for simple pipeline “unexpected token”

Tags: jenkins, groovy, msbuild, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile to execute code analysis using Sonarcube. When i push a commit the Jenkins build triggers but throws an exception on the following line in the Jenkinsfile :

```
 -Dsonar.sources=. \
```

with the following stack trace :
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 21: unexpected token: . @ line 21, column 28.
-Dsonar.sources=. 
^
1 error

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:350)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:144)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:234)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:168)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
```

This is my Jenkinsfile :

```
    pipeline {
            agent any
            stages {
                stage('Checkout'){
                    steps{
                        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/develop']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'Golide', url: 'https://github.com/Username/MyRepo.git']]])
                    }
                }
                stage('Build') {
                        steps {
                            bat "\"${tool 'MSBuild'}\" PaySys.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /t:build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=\"Any CPU\" /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl=c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\"
                        }
                }
                stage('Quality Gate') {
     steps {
       script {
       def MSBuildScannerHome = tool 'MSBuild_SonarScanner';
           withSonarQubeEnv("LocalSonar") {
           bat "${MSBuildScannerHome}\\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end"
           -Dsonar.projectKey=PaySys \
           -Dsonar.sources=. \
           -Dsonar.css.node=. \
           -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \
           -Dsonar.login=dgdhd6585gjgkgkfkfflf7584949"
               }
           }
       }
   }
            }
}
```

MSBuild_SonarScanner refers to Jenkins' **SonarScanner for MSBuild installation** and LocalSonar refers to the Jenkins' **SonarQube installation**.
Two questions :

1. What is wrong with my groovy script ?
2. Is my configuration sufficient/correct enough to trigger code analysis

Comment: It looks like you need to use multiline script syntax here. Wrap your bat script into `'''` quotes

Comment: ' bat "${MSBuildScannerHome}\\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end" '

Comment: Or this :  ' bat "${MSBuildScannerHome}\\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end"
           -Dsonar.projectKey=PaySys \
           -Dsonar.sources=. \
           -Dsonar.css.node=. \
           -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \
           -Dsonar.login=dgdhd6585gjgkgkfkfflf7584949" '

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use multiline script syntax here. Wrap your bat script into `'''` quotes:

```
bat '''${MSBuildScannerHome}\\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
           -Dsonar.projectKey=PaySys \
           -Dsonar.sources=. \
           -Dsonar.css.node=. \
           -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \
           -Dsonar.login=dgdhd6585gjgkgkfkfflf7584949'''
```